# Data not fetching in Hibernate but fetching in SQL with same equal condition

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, datetime, hql

`SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME> WHERE date_date_time = '2025-04-01 10:16:12'` is fetching data from SQL.

But in Hibernate, the same date ('2025-04-01 10:16:12') is not matching with the column and giving the `null` result set.

BUT, when I query using `LIKE '2025-04-01 10:16:12'`, it is giving the result set same as I was getting in SQL query. There is nothing wrong with the code, it is working fine for all other columns except SQL COLUMN TYPE "DATETIME"

Comment: Try to post the HQL you have prepared.
I normally use query parameters to append the values in hql. it never failed even with dates. try this approach once and let me know.